# clearcase merge with beyond compare

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I have few xml files to merge in clearcase and its not working with default tool. so, I made changes to map file to use beyond compare 3 as the merge and compare tools. I am not sure now how to merge xml files and it shows only two windows and an option as copy to the right. can someone help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check your settings: [map file for ClearCase 7 or more](https://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs).

```
text_file_delta xcompare    C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 4\BComp.exe
text_file_delta xmerge  C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 4\BComp.exe
```

Second, make sure to use Beyond Compare 3 or 4.

Third, as far as I can see, the [three-way merge illustrated here](https://www.scootersoftware.com/features.php) is only for the pro version, not the standard one.

[image: https://www.scootersoftware.com/images/TextMerge.png]

Comment: I think the third one is the problem. I have a licensed standard version.

Comment: @user2636464 Then it makes sense. Maybe use kdiff3 instead?